# How is Enumerator created with for in construction destroyed?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, enumerator

I have a collection derived from TCollection, implementing GetEnumerator so I can use it in a construction like

```
for lElem in lCollection do
```

The enumerator is derived from TObject, exactly like the standard enumerators supplied by Delphi and therefor doesn't have an owner.

The Delphi help mentions that if the enumerator supports IDisposable is it will be disposed of, but that is for .NET only of course.

What I was wondering is, how and when and by who the enumerator instance is freed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For each for-enum statement compiler generates code that roughly corresponds to this pseudocode:

```
enumerator := list.GetEnumerator;
try
  while enumerator.MoveNext do
    do something with enumerator.Current;
finally
  enumerator.Free;
end;
```

The code above is generated for enumerators that are implemented as class instances. If your enumerator is implemented as an interface, the last line would not call .Free but merely decrement interface reference count allowing it to be destroyed.

Comment: Actually, it is in an implicit `try...finally` block; the actual generated code also depends on the kind of enumerator (class, record or interface). Oh and I know about the "actually thing" http://twitter.com/#!/migueldeicaza/status/38420006018486272

Comment: @Jeroen: I was trying to be concise but there's always somebody that complains ... ;)

Comment: I presume the try/finally is skipped when you are using a record, well so long as the record contains no managed types itself

Comment: It is. The example above was for class-based enumerators.

Comment: @gabr and presumably you've deduced all this by reverse engineering? Am I right in my assertion that this is not documented, is an implementation detail and is subject to change in a future release?

Comment: I remember a session, but forgot it was by Danny Thorpe or someone else from the Delphi team, mentioning the try...finally thing.

Answer (score 1):

It's freed automatically once it is no longer needed. The compiler generates code to do that so that you don't need to. When the disposal happens is an implementation detail.